# Is there a formula to transform data from one cell into a table?

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I am using Amazon Mechanical Turk to transcribe receipt data. Amazon returns a CSV that is quite unreadable at first sight. URL to CSV file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QR4cgdVrkYwRni3YM5Dc_umIKFGiX_0k/view?usp=sharing

But when you import it into excel a set the Delimiter to Comma it is at least readable. Here is a URL to the excel file(Please download it and open with excel this makes it a lot better): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Noj4UUMd-p1iYKIWDgKURQUzCdhu5Ck1/view?usp=sharing

But then Excel puts all the answers of the transcriber in one cell called "Answer.taskAnswers".

Desired outcome: The values of the transciber in an table like this (check this URL: https://i.ibb.co/vjf0t0c/Prefered-formatting-of-cell-Answer-task-Answers-2.png)

Possible solution 1: A way to format the CSV file to make it look something like the table from "desired outcome".

Possible solution 2: 
A formula that generates another table (possibly on another sheet) of "Answer.taskAnswers" that looks like the table from "desired outcome".

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: You can come a long way with formulas but the fact that the weight is not there for all 5 products kind of makes it difficult.

Comment: Each cell in the `Answer.taskAnswers` column is a JSON document.  That's going to be tough to extract with formulas.

Comment: you might want to give `#powerquery` a shot

Comment: Did you import the CSV using Power Query (Get & Transform)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** M-code changed to allow for varying numbers of columns (products) in the csv JSON string

From the appearance of your output, I am guessing that you used `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform`) to input the data.

If that is the case, you can edit the Query to obtain the output you are looking for.  (If not, you can just use it anyway for the whole process).

The column from which you want the output parsed is in JSON format, and PQ has a built-in parser.

I worked from your original CSV file you provided.

We delete the irrelevant columns and blank rows, parse the JSON string, and then rearrange the data.

All of the steps except the custom column formula, can be done from the GUI.

The custom column formula extracts the elements from the JSON string in the relevant column:  `=Json.Document([Answer.taskAnswers])`

You can just paste the M-code into the Advanced Editor in PQ, and then examine the steps in the GUI to see what's going on.
You will also have to edit the `Source` line to reflect where you are actually getting the source data (and that can be a URL instead of a file)

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\Stackoverflow data for question about cell formating (1).csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=31, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{"Answer.taskAnswers"}),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Other Columns", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Blank Rows", "strJSON", each Json.Document([Answer.taskAnswers])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Answer.taskAnswers"}),
    #"Expanded strJSON" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "strJSON"),
    #"Expanded strJSON1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded strJSON", "strJSON", List.Union(List.Transform(#"Expanded strJSON"[strJSON], each Record.FieldNames(_)))),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Expanded strJSON1", {"purchaseTime", "purchaseDate", "storeName"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"-"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Attribute.2", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Sorted Rows", List.Distinct(#"Sorted Rows"[Attribute.1]), "Attribute.1", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Attribute.2"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"storeName", "purchaseDate", "purchaseTime", "product", "price", "weight", "quantity"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns",{{"purchaseDate", type date}, {"purchaseTime", type time}, {"price", Currency.Type}, {"quantity", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

The original GUI generated M-code had this line which names the JSON columns specifically.  It would not adapt to changes in numbers of products.

```
#"Expanded strJSON1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded strJSON", "strJSON", {"price-1", "price-2", "price-3", "price-4", "price-5", "product-1", "product-2", "product-3", "product-4", "product-5", "purchaseDate", "purchaseTime", "quantity-1", "quantity-2", "quantity-3", "quantity-4", "quantity-5", "storeName", "weight-1", "weight-5", "weight-3"}, {"price-1", "price-2", "price-3", "price-4", "price-5", "product-1", "product-2", "product-3", "product-4", "product-5", "purchaseDate", "purchaseTime", "quantity-1", "quantity-2", "quantity-3", "quantity-4", "quantity-5", "storeName", "weight-1", "weight-5", "weight-3"}),
```

So I have modified that line in the M-Code above, so as to take care of that problem.

**Output**

[image]

*GUI Steps*

[image]

Comment: That's a lot of steps but brilliantly done :) ++. Must say I'm having a hard time to follow all steps (I'm defo not that advanced with PQ)

Comment: @JvdV Tks. It might be doable with fewer steps, but I, too, am trying to educate myself about PQ and am using the GUI for most of the steps. The key, of course, is the format of the relevant column.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You're the man! First off al an excellent explanation, I have very little experience with PQ but it is good to understand. I've tried it out and it showed the desired output :D.Thanks a lot! Know I'm going to test this with more CSV files to see how that goes, I'll let you know.

Comment: @T.deJong Hopefully the other files format will not differ significantly from what you provided.  It can be imported and split using VBA and the legacy import wizard, but it seemed you had probably used the newer wizard, which is based on PQ, for your import, so I expanded on that. Let me know if there is a problem with other CSV files.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The number of rows (product, price, weight, quantity) in Answer.taskAnswers differs from 1 to around 40. When I tried one CSV with 10 rows in Answer.taskAnswers it returned only the first 5. Is it possible to make the query so that it can process a variable amount of rows in the cell of Answer.taskAnswers?  The rest of the CSV stays the same, only the values of id and stuff change.

Comment: @T.deJong I thought I had made the change to take care of an unlimited number of products. Can you provide a link to a csv file with more than 5 products for testing?

Comment: @T.deJong i just tested with 6 products and it seemed to work.  Are you sure you are using the updated m-code?

Comment: @T.deJong When I examine the raw csv file at the link you provided, I only see five (5) products.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld You're right. The code works as it should be. Thanks a lot for your help!