# Using MID and FIND to extract data from a String into an Excel Cell

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

I have to Extract information from a json String for that I am trying to use Excel to extract the tag and the value of the tag within quotations into separate cells and eventually make a table, which will be easier for editing.

For Example: After I paste the data in an excel Cell:

```
"record_data":"[{\"fixed_leg\":[{\"calc_period_bus_center\":[\"Tgt\"],\"calc_period_bus_day_conv\":\"MOD \",\"calc_period\":\"12M\",\"calc_period\":\"8\",\"dcf\":\"30/360\",\"effective_date\":\"2021-04-08\",\"effective_date_ \":[\"Tgt\"],\"effective_date_bus_day_conv\":\"FOLLOWING\",\"final_principal_exchange\":\"FALSE\",\"fixed_rate\":\"0.0311\",\"initial_principal_exchange\":\"FALSE\",\"ntl_amount\":\"96\",\"ntl_ccy\":\"EUR\",\"pay_dates_relative_to\":\"CalculationPeriodEndDate\",\"pay_offset\":\"2D\",\"pay_offset_bus_center\":[\"Tgt\"],\"pay_offset_bus_day_conv\":\"MOD\",\"pay_period_bus_center\":[\"Tgt\"],\"pay_period_bus_day_conv\":\"MOD\",\"pay_period_freq\":\"12M\",\"payer_party\":\"US\",\"receiver_party\":\"GFIL\",\"resettable_ntl\":\"FALSE\",\"termination_date\":\"2026-04-08\",\"termination_date r\":[\"Tgt\"],\"termination_date_bus_day_conv\":\"MOD\"}],]"
}
```

I want to extract the Tag name and value to paste in other excel cells but due to limited knowledge about excel, I am struggling.

I have used 
`=MID(A2,FIND("calc_period_bus_center:",A2,1),A2)`

but that does only return an error #VALUE

Comment: vba would be better see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba

Comment: Third argument for `MID` is the number of characters to return.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57761298/9758194). Looks like the same type of question to me :)

Answer (score 1):

2 points:  First, the third argument of `MID` is a number (how many character to return).  If you change this from `A2` to `LEN(A2)`, it will pull everything until the end of the string.

Secondly, you are searching for the string *"calc_period_bus_center:"*.  However, this **does not exist** in the string you are searching:

> "record_data":"[{\"fixed_leg\":[{\"**calc_period_bus_center**\":[\"Tgt\"],\"calc_period_bus_day_conv\":\"MOD \",\"calc_period\":\"12M\",\"calc_period\":\"8\",\"dcf\":\"30/360\",\"effective_date\":\"2021-04-08\",\"effective_date_ \":[\"Tgt\"],\"effective_date_bus_day_conv\":\"FOLLOWING\",\"final_principal_exchange\":\"FALSE\",\"fixed_rate\":\"0.0311\",\"initial_principal_exchange\":\"FALSE\",\"ntl_amount\":\"96\",\"ntl_ccy\":\"EUR\",\"pay_dates_relative_to\":\"CalculationPeriodEndDate\",\"pay_offset\":\"2D\",\"pay_offset_bus_center\":[\"Tgt\"],\"pay_offset_bus_day_conv\":\"MOD\",\"pay_period_bus_center\":[\"Tgt\"],\"pay_period_bus_day_conv\":\"MOD\",\"pay_period_freq\":\"12M\",\"payer_party\":\"US\",\"receiver_party\":\"GFIL\",\"resettable_ntl\":\"FALSE\",\"termination_date\":\"2026-04-08\",\"termination_date r\":[\"Tgt\"],\"termination_date_bus_day_conv\":\"MOD\"}],]"
>   }

Remove the Colon (`:`):  `=MID(A2,FIND("calc_period_bus_center",A2,1),Len(A2))`  (Or add the `\"` before the colon instead)

Now, presuming you want the bit in square brackets after that, you can use a double-`FIND` to find the first appearance of "]" after "calc_period_bus_center", like so:

```
FIND("]", A2, FIND("calc_period_bus_center",A2,1))
```

You can then use this to trim down further with `LEFT`:

```
=MID(LEFT(A2, FIND("]", A2, FIND("calc_period_bus_center",A2,1))), FIND("calc_period_bus_center",A2,1), Len(A2))
```

This will give you *"calc_period_bus_center\":[\"Tgt\"]"*, so `SUBSTITUTE` the first bit:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(LEFT(A2, FIND("]", A2, FIND("calc_period_bus_center",A2,1))), FIND("calc_period_bus_center",A2,1), LEN(A2)),"calc_period_bus_center\"":","")
```

> [\"Tgt\"]

Comment: Thank you it did work but I am not sure it was clear or i couldn't explain properly, i want to get both calc_period_bus_center and the value "Tgt" in separate cells for example:
CELL 1                                CELL 2
calc_period_bus_center          Tgt
calc_period_bus_day_conv   MOD

Comment: calc_period_bus_center Tgt
calc_period_bus_day_conv MOD
calc_period 12M
calc_period_roll 8
dcf 30/360

Comment: @xack That sounds like something that you should probably be trying to do with VBA instead...  (e.g. the `SPLIT` function can use `","` to break up rows, and `":"` to split up the columns)